# Identifying the instrument for pitched percussion in this track

Tags: transcription, percussion, mallet-percussion

I am transcribing all parts of [“The Mighty Star Lion” from Between the Lions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXOFny8WaV4&pp=ygUQbWlnaHR5IHN0YXIgbGlvbg%3D%3D), and everything has been straightforward except figuring out what instrument plays the ostinato pitched percussion. To me, it sounds like a kalimba but much more percussive. There is still a bit of pitch there (see below). I have sampled the following instruments, and none of them seem to match (except perhaps if they’re heavily muted):

- Marimba
- Kalimba
- Balafon
- …and other similar idiophone instruments.

Any suggestions on what this instrument could be or how the sound was built?

P.S. It’s not essential to my question, but here is my best attempt at notating the pitches I hear in this pitched percussion part:

[image: 4 measures of percussion ostinato]

Comment: It sounds like a string instrument being played with sticks (sounds closer to col legno violin than dulcimer, but you could never do that on a violin) it also reminds me of Africa by Toto if you can manage to identify that